# Basic Punctuation Symbol Errors

Tags: html, grammar, punctuation

I'm receiving data from my database, and I'm showing it through echo statements, but for some reason all the basic punctuation eg (',") are all returning small diamonds with Questionmarks inside of them, can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I'm just using basic commas in basic HTML <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Please post your resulting HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need to escape some of those special characters.  Here is a list of escape codes that you can use:

[Escape Character Codes](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)

If using these codes doesn't work, make sure that the actual document encoding matches the UTF-8 encoding specified.  This can be examined in a text editor like Notepad++.